# Firebase distance querying using Geoflutterfire2 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

I'm trying to use the [Geoflutterfire2 package](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2) to query for users in my Firebase DB that are within a specified distance of the current user. I have all the geohashing pieces working but when I run the query the first time, I only ever get back the authenticated user as a result. When I run it the second time and every time thereafter, then I get back the correct and complete results.

One caveat is that I am trying to run this as a one-time query rather than leave it as an open stream, as I don't want or need the results to be constantly updated. I only need to show current results when the user manually kicks off the query.

Here is the code I'm using to run the query through Geoflutterfire2. I'm doing this as a custom action from within Flutterflow, so it may vary slightly from standard Flutter code (i.e. usage of "UsersRecord"). There are no errors thrown, and I can see in the console that on the first run, only the one current user document is returned when the await call has completed, even though it does appear as if the within method in Geoflutterfire2 continues to gather the rest of the complete data afterwards. That might be why it works on the second run, I'm not sure. Because I'm relying on Geoflutterfire2 for most of the work, it's a bit difficult for me to troubleshoot their code. But I have imported it into my project and added a bunch of print statements throughout, to determine what I have above. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
import 'package:geoflutterfire2/geoflutterfire2.dart';

final geo = GeoFlutterFire();

Future<List<UsersRecord>?> getNearbyUsers(
  LatLng centerPoint,
  double maxDistance,
) async {
  // Create a geoFirePoint
  GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(
      latitude: centerPoint.latitude, longitude: centerPoint.longitude);

  // get the collection reference or query
  var collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  double radius = maxDistance;
  String field = 'location';

  var snapshots = await geo
      .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
      .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true)
      .first;

  // Convert snapshots to UsersRecord objects
  return snapshots
      .map((snapshot) => UsersRecord.fromSnapshot(snapshot))
      .toList();
```

Also, if there are other ways to accomplish this sort of one-time distance query without the use of Geoflutterfire2 (or Geoflutterfire), please let me know. I'm very green to all of this and I'm also not married to using Geoflutterfire2. My only requirements are that I return documents within a specified distance by geohash and that I'm running a one-time query on demand. Thanks!

Comment: "a better way" is subjective, so likely not gonna lead to great answers. But if the code you shared doesn't work, edit your question to show the error message and/or the results of local debugging you've done.

Comment: Thanks Frank, did my best to update and hopefully haven't written a novel that no one will read. Btw I watched your talk on this and I basically want to do EXACTLY what you did - take a given center point, a radius, and click a button to show one-time results. I just don't know how to turn what you did into functioning Flutter code :-/